# Не работает скрипт для инстаграмма

Tags: бот, instagram

я впервые пишу о помощи на stackoverflow. По этому прошу прощение за возможное неправильное оформление.
Проблема заключается в коде ниже, раньше он запускался и работал без ошибок, сейчас при запуске он выбивает ошибку в консоли "Uncaught TypeError: window.__bufferedErrors is undefined
onerror https://www.instagram.com/timatiofficial/:52
setInterval handler* debugger eval code:15"

Есть люди которые могут помочь разобраться в чем ошибка? Буду рад любой помощи.

```
if (location.href.indexOf("instagram.com")==-1)
{
console.log("Скрипт необходимо запускать в чьём-то профиле Instagram.\nНапример, https://www.instagram.com/timatiofficial/")
}
else if (parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName('g47SY')[1].title.split(' ').join('').split(',').join(''))<3000000)
{
console.log("На аккаунте " + document.getElementsByClassName("AC5d8")[0].innerHTML + " недостаточно подписчиков для работы скрипта.")
console.log("Выбери кого-то, у кого больше 3 миллионов подписчиков. \nНапример, https://www.instagram.com/timatiofficial/");
}
else
{
time=prompt("Введите количество секунд между действиями","30");
a=document.getElementsByClassName("_6VtSN");
function godsmack(){a[0].click();b=document.getElementsByClassName("-Cab_");if(b.length>0){b[0].click();}}
setInterval(godsmack,time*1000);
console.log("Скрипт запущен.");
console.log("Интервал между действиями равен " + time + " сек.");
console.log("При закрытии данной вкладки работа скрипта будет завершена.");
```

Comment: Вероятнее всего истанграм ваши запросы блочат

Comment: У вас работает этот скрипт?

Comment: Мне очень интерсно как эта часть кода у меня может заработать?

Comment: Нужно зайти в Инстаграм под своим логином и паролем, затем нужно выбрать аккаунт в котором число подписчиков превышает 3 мл. Нужно открыть консоль и вставить код выше, затем выбрать интервал и запустить его. Скрипт будет отписываться и подписываться на человека пока вы не перезагрузите или не закроете вкладку. И со временем у вас будут появляться подписчики. Я честно не знаю как оно работает, но им легко можно набрать себе подписчиков.